# Exception problems

Tags: python

telling me there is a ValueError exception when I have that covered. Confused why I keep getting the error.

```
def readHourlyRate():
    try:
       rate = float(input('Hourly Rate:$')) 
       if rate < 20:
           print("Must be atleast $20.00/ hour")
    except ValueError:
        print("\nInvalid Hourly Rate, must be atleast $20.00/hour.")
        return rate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following:-

```
def readHourlyRate():
    try:
       rate = float(input('Hourly Rate:$'))
    except ValueError:
       print("\nInvalid Hourly Rate, must be atleast $20.00/hour.")
       return
    if rate < 20:
           print("Must be atleast $20.00/ hour")
    return rate
readHourlyRate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this **working** example :

```
def readHourlyRate():
    try:
        rate = float(input('Hourly Rate:$'))
        if rate < 20:
            print("Must be atleast $20.00/ hour")
    except ValueError:
        print("\nInvalid Hourly Rate, must be atleast $20.00/hour.")
        return rate

readHourlyRate()
```

And putting a string as input, this is the traceback you get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/[...].py", line 3, in readHourlyRate
    rate = float(input('Hourly Rate:$'))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'sdfsdf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/[...].py", line 10, in <module>
    readHourlyRate()
  File "C:/[...].py", line 8, in readHourlyRate
    return rate
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rate' referenced before assignment
```

By carefully reading it, we can see that during the handling of the `ValueError` exception raised by our invalid input, another unhandled exception was raised because we ae trying to return the `rate` variable.
However, this variable was never declared nor assigned because a `ValueError` was raised while we were trying to do so.

Depending on what you want your program to do, you can then assign a default value in the `except` block like so :

```
except ValueError:
print("Invalid Hourly Rate, must be atleast $20.00/hour.")
print("Returning default value 20")
return 20
```

Or just let the error propagate

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def readHourlyRate():
    rate = input('Hourly Rate:$')
    try:
       if float(rate) < 20:
           print("Must be atleast $20.00/ hour")
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nInvalid Hourly Rate, must be atleast $20.00/hour.")
        return rate

readHourlyRate()
```